# Получить число int после парсинга html страницы

Tags: python

ДД прошу помощи! После парсинга страницы через bs find_all получаю такой результат. Необходимо получить 6 числовых значений, чтобы потом сравнить их между собой (первые 3 и последние 3)

```
[<td align="center" valign="top" width="33%">
                                                <div class="fight-stat">
                            22                        </div>
                        <div class="fight-stat-icon strength"></div>
                    </td>, <td align="center" valign="top" width="33%">
                                                <div class="fight-stat">
                            32                        </div>
                        <div class="fight-stat-icon dexterity"></div>
                    </td>, <td align="center" valign="top" width="33%">
                                                <div class="fight-stat">
                            33                        </div>
                        <div class="fight-stat-icon critical"></div>
                    </td>, <td align="center" valign="top" width="33%">
                        <div class="fight-stat">
                            28                        </div>
                    </td>, <td align="center" valign="top" width="33%">
                        <div class="fight-stat">
                            35                        </div>
                    </td>, <td align="center" valign="top" width="33%">
                        <div class="fight-stat">
                            22                        </div>
                    </td>, <td align="center" width="33%">
```

Answer (score 2):

***Пример:***

```py
...
li = soup.find_all(...)  # Ваш результат

fight_stats = []
for x in li:
    fight_stat = int(x.find('div', {'class': 'fight-stat'}).get_text().strip())
    fight_stats.append(fight_stat)

print(fight_stats)
...
```

Comment: `fight_stats = [int(x.find('div', {'class': 'fight-stat'}).get_text().strip()) for x in li]` :)

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

выдает такую же ошибку, как когда я пытался сделать

`for x in li:
  fight_stat = x.find('div', {'class': 'fight-stat'}).text`

Comment: @krokus Тогда уточните, пожалуйста, формат входных данных, а именно: тип элементов списка, строковое представление элементов списка. Увы, то, что Вы привели в вопросе, не является валидной структурой. Я не знаю, как Вы получили это.